# JavaFX: ImageView shows Image only once

Tags: java, javafx

In my JavaFX application I use a TreeView. The single TreeItems contain an image. Unfortunately, the image is shown only once.

[image: a gif showing the problem]

The code for loading the image looks like the following. It is called every time the TreeView changes. The `Image`s are cached in a `Map` ("icons"). Thus, a new `ImageView` is created every time.

```
public final ImageView getImage(final String imageConstant) {
    final Image img;
    if (icons.containsKey(imageConstant)) {
        img = icons.get(imageConstant);
    }
    else {
        if (isRunFromJAR) {
           img = new Image("/path/" + imageConstant, iconSizeWidth,
                    iconSizeHeight, false, false);
        }
        else {
            img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageConstant), iconSizeWidth,
                    iconSizeHeight, false, false);
        }
        icons.put(imageConstant, img);
    }
    return new ImageView(img);
```

In the `updateItem` method of my `TreeCell`s, the `ImageView` returned above is stored into a field called `icon`. The field is used in the following code, also from `updateItem`:

```
if (icon == null) {
        setGraphic(label);
    }
    else {
        final HBox hbox = new HBox(ICON_SPACING);
        final Label iconLabel = new Label("", icon);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(iconLabel, label);
        setGraphic(hbox);
    }
```

But for some reason, the problem shown in the gif occurs.

### **Update**

Actually, the ImageViews were cached internally, which led to de-duplication. Using multiple ImageViews is the solution.

Comment: If you need more pieces of code to investigate, please to not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Are you getting the image from a file every time it is needed (because you change the TreeView)?

Comment: Do you use a new `ImageView` instance for every place you show the image?

Comment: No I don't. Im sorry, this is really a thing I should have noticed myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the ImageView returned above is stored into a field called icon.The field is used in the following code...

The **ImageView** is type of Node. A Node can only have **one parent** at a time!
So don't store/cache a ImageView(-Node). Create new ImageView-Nodes.

**Edit:** 
As pointed out in the comments by James_D:

> ...you can use the same **Image**(-Object) for every ImageView...

Comment: Note you can use the same `Image` for every `ImageView`, which will save resources while still meeting JavaFX's "nodes can only appear once in a scene" rule.